# How to create relative url imports in Typescript and Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

Hi I am trying to understand how typescript know wheat @angular is and how it know to import it. I know that from  a Javascript level this can be configured to tell SystemJS where to look but from a Typescript level I can understand where this is achieved.

My current application has the following structure:

[image]

When loading native angular 2 components we have the following import url:

> import {Component} from '@angular/core';

From this somehow Typescript knows that it can find the components in libs/@angular.

I know that at the javascript level this configuration is done like this:

```
(function (global) {
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'libs/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'libs/rxjs',
    '@commercify': 'app'
};

.....

var config = {
    map: map,
};
System.config(config);
```

})(this);

As it can bee seen I have created @commercify': 'app' that should point to app but this does not tell typescript anything. How can I configure typescript so that it knows where @commercify is found?

At the moment I am getting a cannot find module in Visual Studio for this import:

```
import { CategoriesComponent } from '@commercify/catalog/categories/categories.component';
```

The functioning url looks like this:

'import { CategoriesComponent } from '../../catalog/categories/categories.component';'

I would like to avoid adding ../../ and directly point to the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you want is **"non-relative"** import.

In your tsconfig.json add the following, if needed restart VS Code

```
"module": "systemjs",
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

How module resolution works in Typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html